# How can I know *exactly* when my name_new domain is ready for the name_firstupdate step?

Tags: namecoin, domain-registering

The FAQ very vaguely says "Wait at least 12 blocks", but it doesn't make much sense to me.

Unless I have totally misunderstood how this works, once the `name_new`d domain is in the chain, I should safely be able to proceed to the next step... so how can I know *exactly* if it is ready? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you can issue your `name_firstupdate` transaction whenever you're ready (in particular, right after doing the `name_new`).  It won't be included in a block until the `name_new` is mature (12 confirms) but should be picked up shortly after that happens.

I don't have any source for this other than recent experience, but my names are showing up when I do `name_list` so I take it that they are properly registered.

EDIT: I thought about it a little, and I suppose you should wait a little bit (at least until your `name_new` is included in a block).  The reason being that nobody can know what name you're trying to register until you do `name_firstupdate`, and so they can't steal it from you.  Sending both the `name_new` and the `name_firstupdate` is vulnerable because someone can quickly issue their own `name_new` for the same name, and depending on luck (or in the worst-case, their control of a significant hashrate) claim it before you can.

Someone more familiar with the intimate details of how requests for the same name are resolved can comment on whether this scenario is possible or not.

Comment: Then, how can I know if my name_new has been included in a block?

Comment: When you do `listtransactions` there's a field labeled `confirmations`; if that is non-zero then it has been included in that many blocks.

Alternatively you can check the block explorer at http://explorer.dot-bit.org/; look for your transaction to show up in the list at the bottom.